# No minicom output when running from script

Tags: bash, minicom

I have this line:

```
timeout -s SIGKILL 55s minicom -C $file.txt
```

It works fine when I run it directly from the terminal (even with the timeout) but when I run it from the bash script, it creates the files, but they're all empty.

Comment: SIGKILL is a hard enough shutdown that it stops a program from flushing its output -- anything that's still in the memory buffer is lost. Use SIGTERM instead.

Comment: The reason this doesn't happen from a terminal is liable to be a difference in behavior based on `isatty()` -- terminal stdout is line-buffered by default, whereas stdout going to regular files is fully buffered (so it's written in larger chunks to reduce round-trips into kernelspace).

Comment: Didn't work with SIGTERM either. Is there a way I can change the buffering behavior so it writes as it goes?

Comment: If a program doesn't override libc's defaults, and the local platform is Linux, you can use `stdbuf` to configure the defaults it uses. That said, if switching to SIGTERM doesn't help, it may not in fact be a buffering problem.

Comment: That said, one other thing you can try to test whether it's a problem related to where stdin and stdout are attached is to use `unbuffer` or other tools that emulate a TTY.

Comment: ...where I'd be going next, though, is using syscall-tracing tools (strace, sysdig, etc) to log how the program executes and see where it's getting stuck -- including whether it's _trying_ to write output at all.

Comment: After debugging I realized that the kill isn't the problem. When not running from the script, the contents are already in the file before it gets killed. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I still recommend using sysdig or similar to trace execution.